# How do I tune work_mem based on logs of temp files?

Tags: postgresql

In an [article](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/architecture-and-tuning-memory-postgresql-databases) I found that one heuristic to tune `work_mem` is to:

> 1. Start with low value: 32-64MB
> 2. Then look for ‘temporary file’ lines in logs
> 3. Set to 2-3 times the largest temp file

Running:

```
SHOW log_temp_files; -- res: 0
```

I found that logging temp files is enabled.

1. What are the drawbacks of logging temp_files?
2. How can I query temp_file logs?
3. Is there a better heuristic for estimating the right value for `work_mem`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heuristic is good. Basically, if you get temp files “too often” (deliberately vague), it might be a win to increase `work_mem`.

If you change `log_temp_files`, you will get messages in the log file. You need operating system access to the database server to read those.

But there is an alternative: the statistics view [`pg_stat_database`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-DATABASE-VIEW) has two columns:

> - `temp_files` `bigint` Number of temporary files created by queries in this database.
> - `temp_bytes` `bigint` Total amount of data written to temporary files by queries in this database.

These statistics are cumulative, so you have to query the values regularly and see if they increase considerable. If yes, it might be a good idea to try a higher setting for `work_mem`.

Answer (score 2):

This advice seems pretty questionable to me.  It is based on the premise that using temp files is bad.  They aren't bad, they are certainly better than crashing or swapping into oblivion.  But if you accept that premise, why start low and then creep up on the "correct" value?  Just set work_mem ridiculously high to start with, and be done with it.  (Until you realize it was a mistaken premise.)

Also, any single temp file is limited to 1GB.  If you need more than that amount of temp space it uses multiple files, but each file gets logged separately. So just looking at the largest logged line will not show you the max amount of temp space any single statement has used.  (This fact does kind of limit the damage this advice can do, though, as you at least wouldn't set it to more than 3GB)

> ```
> SHOW log_temp_files; -- res: 0
> ```
>
> I found that logging temp files is disabled.

No, 0 means log everything.  -1 means disabled.

Comment: Updating my question accordingly as I assumed 0 meant off.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable logging of temp files in postgres configuration file (see [log_temp_files](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html), and you will then see in logs, what operations "spill" to disk (sorts, hashing..).

That being said, I don't think this is some silver bullet approach to determine good work_mem value. You can't just multiply some value from logs by 3 and use it as work_mem. It is important to understand, how work_mem works - it is per-backend (per-connection) memory, and per-operation thing.

So you should think something like this: "in typical scenario, how many concurrent users are running memory-intensive things at the same time?". And you should then divide the amount of RAM you want to "reserve" for work_mem (excluding shared buffers, other processes, some reasonable kernel cache, etc.). Yes, it is not exact science. If you have typically one or two concurrent users running heavy sorts, you can set work_mem to 1 GB easily. If you have 500 concurrent users running light queries, you can (and should) set much smaller work_mem.